# Topological Properties closed sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I'm slightly confused with the idea of 'topological properties'
Is closed-ness of a subset of a metric space X a topological property? 
I think it is because if a subset is closed under 1 metric then it should be closed under another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, but for the wrong reason. Being closed is a topological property because it depends only upon the topology induced by the metric, not by the metric itself. For instance, being bounded is *not* a topological property, because a set may be bounded with respect to a metric and unbounded with respect to another equivalent metric.

On the other hand, it is false that if a set is closed with respect to a metric then it will automatically be closed with respect to any other metric. For instance, in $\mathbb R$, $[0,1)$ is closed with respect to the discrete metric, but not with respect to the usual one.

Comment: but why does it depend only on the topology induced by the metric?

Comment: Because being closed means that its complement is open and the set of open subsets **is** the topology.

Comment: Thank you for your clarity!!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Comment: Is it therefore true that being closed and bounded is not a topological property?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.